# How can I sort objects returned by EF according to a list of IDs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables:

```
User {
    PK: UserId
    ...
}

Product {
    PK: ProductId, 
    FK: UserId
    ...
}
```

I have a list of `ProductId`s in random format. I do not want to sort the output result and I would like to include User data as well for each product Id.

The below code provides the data in sorted format. How can I avoid this sorting? I want the list of objects to be in the same order as our product list.

```
List<Tables.Product> tblProductList =
    repo.Products
        .Include("User")
        .Where(x => productIdList.Contains(x.ProductId))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: There's no such thing as default sorting. Unless you specify an OrderBy clause, the database will return objects without ordering. They *may* appear ordered because some operations (eg Distinct) use Sort. Even these will be unordered though if the query is expensive enough to be parallelized

Comment: What is `productIdList`? Something loaded from another table or just a list of IDs?

Comment: productIdList contains list of Integer Ids.

Comment: But where does it come from? If it comes from a table, you could include the other table as well and order by some fields on it. If it's just a list of IDs, you have to reorder the results on the client side. There's no way to reorder query results by an arbitrary list of IDs in SQL.

Comment: On the client side you can create a list of `(ProductID,Order)` pairs, join it with the results on ProductID and order by the `Order` column.

Comment: Well, @JyotishSingh, a couple of people went out of their way to reword the question into what *they* think you want. Is this your question though? I vote for "unclear what you're asking" because I still don't know what *you* want.

Comment: @GertArnold I was going to vote the same, but noticed the last sentence, which combined the the post title made me think what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev That's the most likely assumption. I just would have liked to see some more involvement by the OP.

Comment: @IvanStoev & Gert Arnold : The question is I am getting list of product integer ids(9,4,8,100 etc.) let's say from client or azure search, When I try to get data from my local DB using above query(which I have mentioned in my question), I am getting list of objects, First object with productId 4, second with 8, third with 9, fourth with 100 etc however I don't now why above query provides data in sorted format. I hope, I am able to clear my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want the list of objects to be in the same order as our product list.

I assume by *our product list* you mean the `productIdList` variable used for filtering.

You cannot do that in LINQ to Entities, so you have to switch to LINQ to Objects and do the ordering in memory.

One way would be to use [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var tblProductList =
    repo.Products
        .Include("User")
        .Where(x => productIdList.Contains(x.ProductId))
        .AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Objects context
        .OrderBy(x => productIdList.IndexOf(x.ProductId))
        .ToList();
```

Another more performant method (when `productIdList` is big) could be to use intermediate dictionary:

```
var productsById =
    repo.Products
        .Include("User")
        .Where(x => productIdList.Contains(x.ProductId))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ProductId);

var tblProductList = productIdList
    .Select(productId => productsById[productId])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks as always :)

Comment: For 10 productIdList the above query takes 10 seconds. Is there any way to improve It?

Comment: How long takes the original query?

Comment: Original query take 2 to 3 seconds however sometime this query also take 4 to 5 seconds but generally It takes around 10 seconds.

Comment: Hmm, ordering 10 records in memory shouldn't add more than a few milliseconds to your original query. When measuring the original query, you include `ToList()` call, right?

Comment: Yes I am using the same query with ToList(). Let me put It on staging, probably It would impact something.

Comment: Query is fine however Is It possible to include some specific column like UserName, FirstName, LastName etc form Users table instead of whole Users table data?

Comment: Sure it is possible (as with any query). However in such case the result cannot be `Product` entity, you have to create some class with the required fields from `Product` and `User`, remove the `Include` call and add `Select` after `Where`. As soon as the resut contains `ProductId`, the remaining part wll be unaffected.

Comment: Lets say I have a class called "ProductSearchResponseModel" which contains all the required property of product and user then what will be the query?

Comment: `repo.Products.Where(x => productIdList.Contains(x.ProductId).Select(x => new ProductSearchResponseModel {  ProductId = x.ProductId /* ,other product fields ...*/, UserName = x.User.Name /* ,other user fields */ }) /* ... same as in the answer */`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks once again :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var tblProductList=(from product in repo.Products
                   join user in repo.Users on product.UserId equals user.UserId  
                   select new { Product=product,User=user}).toList();
```

Comment: ORMs use relations, not joins. There's absolutely no reason to use `join` when the relation is already defined. In fact, it's a bug to use joins instead of mapping relations